# How to implement static with final?

Tags: java, oop

I'm confused about the meaning of `final` and `static` keywords. It's because, as far as I know, `static` creates a separate memory in class. A `static` field can only be accessed from a `static` method. Then, why is there no error when I declare `list` inside a Test constructor?

**First Question**:

```
public Test() {
    list = new ArrayList();
    list.add("foo");
}
```

When I declare

```
public class Test {
    private static List list;

    public Test() {
        list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("foo");    
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
        list = new ArrayList();

        Test t = new Test();
        t.list.add("add");

        System.out.print("Hello " + t.list);    
    }
}
```

It works fine. But when I add `final` with `static`, it does not work.

**Second Question:**

```
public class Test {
    private static final List list;

    public Test() {
        list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("foo");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
        list = new ArrayList();

        Test t = new Test();
        t.list.add("add");

        System.out.print("Hello" + t.list); 
    }
}
```

Please explain how it works internally.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you would like to have explained in your second question?

Comment: before adding final its working.after working final its not working.My second question why its not working and internal mechanism?@bleistift2

Comment: Where did you get "a static filed can only be access from a static method" from. This is simply not true. Fact is, you can't access a non-static field from a static method. All other combinations are allowed.

Answer (score 2):

**Question-1**

Using *static* keyword with an object enables sharing one and the same copy across all the objects of the container class. So if you initialize, reassign that *static* object, it does change for all the objects of that class.
You can create new objects using that *static* reference or reassign it as many times you wish but it will be reflected to all the existing and new objects of the container class. You cannot assign different value for a particular container class object. 
*Static* variables can be accessed from anywhere, anytime even before instantiating the container class, using the class name followed by the variable name.
About accessing *static* variables, you can access it from any *static* or non-*static* method. But in the *static* method you can only use *static* variables or the variables declared in that method only.

**Question-2**

using *final* keyword with an object tells the compiler that there should be only one and single object/value should be associated with the reference being declared as *final*.  *Final* object/variable should be initialized once only at the time of its declaration. Its value/referring object cannot be changed/reassigned  further. This what we call *constant* variable in C++;

Hope it helps.

Cheers..!!

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code and the attached comments.

```
public class Test {

// this can be set only once and only from the static block
private static final List listStaticFinal;

// this is initialized when declared
private static final List listStaticFinalInitialized = new ArrayList();

// this can be set many times from multiple places
private static List listStatic;

// this is initialized when declared
private static List listStaticInitialized = new ArrayList();

static {
    // can set only once from here
    listStaticFinal = new ArrayList();

    // can be set also from here
    listStatic = new ArrayList();
}

public Test() {
    // can be set also from here
    listStatic = new ArrayList();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // can be set also from here
    listStatic = new ArrayList();
}
```

}

**NOTE**: You can set static final fields only in static blocks.

**NOTE**: Java does not have the concept of static class. If you want your class to behave similar to a static class then you can mark your constructor as private.

**NOTE**: when writing static fields consider also the context in which your code will be used and document the code appropriately. For example your code might be used in a multithreading scenario.

**NOTE**: when writing static fields consider also how your code will be tested. Static might create difficulties mocking the corresponding code.

Comment: You can also initialize final static variables when declaring them. For instance, `final static ArrayList list = new ArrayList();` is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Since **final** variable can initialised only once during the startup that's why constructor is allowed to initialise the variable. Here we also got **static** that means you have to initialise the variable during class load. That can be done using static initializer block.

> static{
>           list=new ArrayList();
>       }

Answer (score 0):

As for your first question, the `static` keyword means that the variable will be available even if you do not instantiate the class. For instance, in your examples, `yourClass.list` does reference a list even if you never call `new yourClass()`. Had you left out the `static` keyword, `yourClass.list` *does not yet exist* prior to instatiating the class.

The `final` keyword is for declaring *constants*. That is, after the variable is initialized (having a value assigned to it for the first time), either in the constructor

```
public Test(){
    list = new ArrayList();
}
```

or immediately after declaring it, `private final List list = new ArrayList();`, it is *immutable*. Any attempts of changing it, for instance using another `list = …` statement, result in error.

Comment: This is not true. The list is not immutable, the reference is.

Comment: @sschrass Thanks for pointing that out. I corrected my answer.